# Segmentation of a RGB-D point cloud

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have a scene point cloud (I have coordinates and RGB-D information of each point). The scene consist of some objects point cloud (for example obj1 and obj 2,...). I want to do a segmentation on this scene and provide labeled point cloud data.(for example in out put I can have information of the labeled point clouds,all points of object 1 labeled as 1 and object 2 as 2 and so an.) Is there any accurate method for that?

Answer (score 1):

The best resource to use would probably be the Point Cloud Library (PCL). It has a vast amount of functions and classes for dealing with point clouds including various segmentation methods. I would suggest checking out [this set of segmentation tutorials](http://Color-based%20region%20growing%20segmentation) and finding one that is well suited to your specific use case.